# Riddle me this: Getting away with vandalism

Tags: riddle, rhyme

I came up with this riddle over the holidays but since my family doesn't speak English, you get to be the audience. Exciting!

> You had a thing precious you worked so hard to make
>
> I worked even harder to that treasure break.
>
> Yet no one would yell at me, no one would leer,
>
> my punishment was only applause and cheer.
>
> And from the remains of that which I maimed
>
> a thing much similar (but better!) I claimed.

What exactly could I be talking about?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is it a

> world record

Explanation:

*You had a thing precious you worked so hard to make*

> Worked hard to set a new record

*I worked even harder to that treasure break.*

> To break a record you have to do even better than the last person

*Yet no one would yell at me, no one would leer,*

*my punishment was only applause and cheer.*

> Cheering for the record breaker

*And from the remains of that which I maimed

a thing much similar (but better!) I claimed.*

> Made a new world record, almost the same as the broken one, but better

Answer (score 4):

Is it a

> piñata?

It does

> take hard work to make and [can be associated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi%C3%B1ata#Pi%C3%B1atas_in_Mexico) with Christmas. But its end is a violent one, the culmination of which could elicit cheers and could also release stuff even more prized than the container that until that point had been the focus of attention.

@S. M. was thinking along very similar lines, but maybe

> the [language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pi%C3%B1ata#Asia) spoken by your family is also a clue.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's

> a gift/wrapping paper

*You had a thing precious you worked so hard to make*

> You worked hard to wrap the present

*I worked even harder to that treasure break.*

> Worked even harder to tear apart the wrapping

*Yet no one would yell at me, no one would leer,*

*my punishment was only applause and cheer.*

> People cheered as you opened your present.

*And from the remains of that which I maimed*
*a thing much similar (but better!) I claimed.*

> After tearing away the wrapping, you got to your *actual* gift.

This would also make sense considering

> You came up with it during the holidays, so maybe while you/someone opened a christmas gift. Also makes sense since you mention vandalism in the title.

Comment: Why the downvote? :\

Comment: This _kind of_ fits, but does not seem like an ideal answer. You have applied some of the lines to a present, and some others to the wrapping paper itself. Unwrapping a present is not usually hard, or harder than wrapping it. Also the present is (most likely) not similar to the actual _paper_.

Comment: Just my personal opinion, I don't mind if other people disagree.

Comment: Thank you, just wanted an opinion honestly, seemed like a good answer to me but I can see why it might not be, according to your points.

Comment: I think that the biggest issue is that it can't answer the question _what am I?_, the main question in the riddle. If you answer _present_ it won't fit all clues, and if you answer _wrapping paper_ the same thing happens. That said, it is not a bad answer. A suggestion does not always have to be "correct" to warrant an answer.

Comment: But the question isn't even exactly *what am I?*, that's why I supposed it could be more open ended. Still, the top answer fits a lot better, ofc.

Comment: It's not explicitly stated, but _What __exactly__ could I be talking about?_ strongly implies this. As I said though, this is only my personal interpretation, and opinion. At the end of the day everybody has to make their own choice.

Answer (score 2):

I think the answer could also be

> A diamond

Because:

*You had a thing precious you worked so hard to make*

> Diamonds are formed under extreme conditions in nature, over a long period of time.

*I worked even harder to that treasure break.*

> Since diamonds are such hard materials, breaking them (and specifically cutting them meticulously) is a very difficult and arduous task.

*Yet no one would yell at me, no one would leer,*

*my punishment was only applause and cheer.*

*And from the remains of that which I maimed*

*a thing much similar (but better!) I claimed.*

> Cutting diamonds is a praiseworthy form of art, and a well-cut diamond can appreciate greatly in value.

Answer (score 0):

I thought it might be

> growing the wheat, and then milling it into a flour, and then making a bread out of it.

However, the "applause and cheer" part fits the accepted answer much better, than, say

> "harvest-time celebrations"